# Confused about regex pattern

Tags: regex

What is the difference between  search pattern like `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*` and `[a-zA-Z]*`  ?

Answer (score 8):

The first matches one `[a-zA-Z]` followed by zero or more `[a-zA-Z]`.

The second matches zero or more `[a-zA-Z]`.

---

The first can also be written as `[a-zA-Z]+`.

Comment: Could you explain `.+?` and `.*?`   ?

Comment: it seems `.+?x` that matches `asdfxxcccxxxx` but not the first x

Comment: @cdh, sorry, the comment was wrong. `.+?x` will match anything until the first x, as long as "anything" contains at least one character (`.+` means any character 1 or more times - [example](http://refiddle.com/gcp)). `.*?x` will do the same thing, but even if there's nothing before x (`.*` means any character 0 or more times).

Answer (score 2):

The regex `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*` means that you are mandating that there should be one alpabetic character **optionally** followed by **any** number of alphabets. On the other hand, `[a-zA-Z]*` means that the alphabet mandate is entirely off.

For example, your first regex matches the strings `azxxx`, `abccdef` but fails `2abcd`, `22` and blank strings. But the second regex can match a blank string too.

For the first regex, you may just want to say: `[a-zA-Z]+` instead.